# Page disappears on load

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I have a web application that includes an ExtJS 4.1 grid.

I create the grid(and it is rendered right), but when I load the store, the whole page disappears. I have added a *load* listener on the store and it seems that the results are received successfully.

This problem occurs only in IE8 - Chrome and FireFox display everything right.

How should I fix this?

Comment: @sha By `disappears` I mean that the page becomes blank(white). All its elements are simply gone.

Comment: Anything in the console log? Errors or anything else?

Comment: @sha No errors or anything does appear in the console(IE8 or any other browser). As I have mentioned in the question, I have added a listener for the `load` event on the store and displayed in the console whether it was successful or not. It seems that the results arrive as expected.

Comment: Check your code for some unnecessary commas - like `{ prop: 'name', }`. IE doesn't like those...

Comment: @sha That's not the case this time :)).

Comment: Try to create simple example of it and put it on fiddle or something like that

Comment: @sha I have solved it. Check my answer. Have you had any similar issues? Do you have any idea on how should I make them work together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this problem.

The problem was that I was also using PIE(http://css3pie.com/) and had customized the **strong** tag so that it had a shadow and rounded corners. One of the grid's fields had a few **strong** tags. It seems that the existence of more than one such tag in one cell makes IE8 crash(or something similar), hence the aforementioned problem.

Comment: No, I haven't had anything like this. But you can see now - it would be impossible for anybody to give you an answer. Your problem was in completely different area and you didn't post any relevant code.

Comment: @sha Yes, I see. The thing is that I can't be certain of what is causing the problem. In the future I will try to post some code or to isolate the problem before I post a question here, hoping that someone has faced this before or that someone's hunch might lead to something. Thank you.